# onResult HTTPService

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, events, httpservice, actionresult

I have a HTTPService:

```
    <mx:HTTPService id="scoreService" url="http://" method="POST" result="onResult(event)">
        <s:request xmlns="">
            <name>{..}</name>
            <score>{...}</score>
        </s:request>
    </mx:HTTPService>
```

And a script for (event):

```
private function onResult(e:ResultEvent):void
    {
        if (e.result.status == true)
        {
            currentState='...';
        }
        else 
        {
            Alert.show("...", "...");
        }
    }
```

The problem is that none of the event possibilities fires after I POST data to my php...

Thanks, Yan

Comment: Does the code hit onResult() at all?  If so - what's the value of result?

Comment: "Default decoder could not decode result"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a real URL attribute in the HTTPService -- but I don't know if you edited it out or not.  Try adding this to the HTTPService tag:

```
fault="mx.controls.Alert.show(event.fault.faultString)"
```

You should always have a fault handler too.

Comment: what was the solution?  was it the url?